# Content not stretching

Tags: html, css, footer, stretch

I've been trying recently to make my footer attach to the bottom of the page and make my middle content stretch, so that the footer will be placed correctly, no matter what resolution the website is viewed in.

It's been a while since i was last editing on this website, and i've forgotten most of the things i did to keep the layout maxed, and now i noticed another ERROR :(

My content now wont stretch, so if i place some text in my content area, it will go behind the footer and stretch to the bottom, without the bg image..

Could some of you tell me what is causing this problem? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some things you could do to improve that. I see your footer is position: relative; Don't really understand why... I think it should be position: absolute; and bottom: 0px; so it should fix to the bottom. Having your footer position: fixed; is not a good idea.

The content of your website should have a bottom padding equal to the height of your footer, and that will give you enough room for the footer and won't let any content get below the footer.

Let me know if you understood what I tried to explain and good luck with your project!

Comment: Hey there :)
Yea that seems like a very good solution. I will look into that afterwards.
Right now i'm trying to see if i can fix the stretch problem though. I think it's because i haven't cleared the float of some of the div's in the content area.. 

I was hoping someone could tell me where the problem is happening.

Comment: I think i just fixed it by clearing float after the content div

Comment: Hey again 7th, i fixed the stretch problem, and tested it on the main page.. Allthough if you look under Produkter -> PIXY 35 STD
You will notice, that it's cutting off the bottom of my text.

Comment: It was cutting before, but not anymore... I'll check that in other two browsers... ok, just checked that and it looks fine here. It's pushing the footer and showing all the content as it should

Comment: It's amazing how much it helps asking the question..
Yea i fixed it all now.
Thanks for the advice on the footer 7th.. Much appreciated